# Passing argument to rails helper with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get the contents of a b tag and then use this to query a helper method, in my rails up. But I cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone offer some help please?

"query" is the helper method. And I need to pass it the text that is contained within the b tag. Help..?

```
<div class="col span_1_of_7">
    <section id="feed">
        <div id ="infoFeed">
            <ul style="font: 10px sans-serif;text-align: justify;">
                <script>
                    $(document).click(function(){
                        <% query($("#tooltip b").text();) %>
                    });
                </script>
                <% Story.all.each do |story| %>
                    <li style="border-style:solid;border-top:thick double #000;">
                        <p><h4 style="text-align:left;"><%= link_to story.title, story.url, :target => "_blank" %></h4> 
                        <%= story.description %> <h7><br /><br /><%= story.source %><br /><%= story.date.to_date %></h7></p></li>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <script> $(function() { $('#infoFeed').vTicker();});</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing might be exciting but that is not possible in a Client - Server Web Application.

You need to understand the basics of a web application and understand the line that seperates Server Side code and Client Side code.

Ruby (Rails) - is server side: this means it generates your HTML or JS or CSS and this HTML/JS/CSS are sent to the Client (Browser). In our Browser, the HTML is parsed and drawn on your screen, and then the JavaScript code is executed and it does whatever you want using the HTML sent. This JavaScript cannot directly access the Ruby code on your server.

Alright. Lets see what you have done.

```
$(document).click(function(){
  <% query($("#tooltip b").text();) %>
});
```

OK. You have added a ERB scriptlet inside of your click handler for your `document` (why would you do this?). Ok I am not going to talk to you about your JavaScript errors. Lets address the server - client issue here.

**This is what you expect to happen:**

After the web page is loaded, the text inside the `#tooltip b` gets extracted using the `text` function of jQuery and it will be passed to `query` ruby helper and it does something.

**What Really Happens**

When this page gets generated by Rails, (remember this happens in your server and it DOES NOT EXECUTE YOUR JAVASCRIPT. All it sees is plain text with embedded Ruby using `<% %>`), the query helper gets called and its argument would be this `$("#tooltip b").text();`. I told you this JavaScript will not be executed in server. So this gets passed into the query and ruby does not know what `$("#tooltip b").text();` is. Since its not even a string (see you have no quotes around it), Ruby will probably throw a syntax error.

So the bottom line is! You want JQuery to take contents of `#tooltip b` and pass it to a Ruby function. This will not happen because this JavaScript is itself generated by Ruby and only after this HTML response is built and sent to the client's browser (where there is no Ruby runtime), the JavaScript will be executed.

I hope you understand. Please read this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

---

Alright. So How do you achieve this then. Remember? I said You cannot access Ruby code 'directly'. Does it mean you can do it indirectly somehow? Yes! As you suggested in the comment use Ajax.

You need to write an action that will help you call the `query` method. Then you need to do a AJAX call to the URL corresponding to the action you just wrote and pass the result of `$("#tooltip b").text();` as the data. In your action obtain this data from the params hash and pass it to your helper and do your processing. Return result as js or json as per your wish.

ok Steps:

1. Create an action in Rails and add a route to access this action.
2. Inside the action obtain the data being sent from client side from the `params` hash. I think you know how to do this. And pass it into the query helper method. (You need to include your helper module in your controller for this to work)
3. use the `respond_to`  or just `render` to return the result as `json` or `js` depending upon your situation.
4. In the Client Side, add a ajax call to the url of the action  and pass the data. Add a success callback and this will receive whatever you sent from your action. Use it to do whatever you want.

Please refer resources on the web. This is not a place to write tutorials.

Comment: Lol.. can you help point out how please.. I am trying to get this last part done before tomorrow.. and the app is perfect execpt for this one last thing..

Comment: stevanity.. thanks for the reply. Is there any chance you can break it down for me into steps? I can do ajax calls in html but when I need to  do it in rails it gets very confusing.

Comment: Okay. Ill help you a little bit. But there's so much resource online just a google search away. Please accept the answer if youre satisfied.

Comment: Stevanity.. I have looked but it is very confusing. Never the I think you might have got me over the line... THANKS! Serious.. I really appreciate it.